# Programmatically generate Django sqlsequencereset

Tags: python, django

How can I programmatically generate the SQL generated by Django's `manage.py sqlsequencereset` command?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to call the management command itself programmatically (rather than from the command line), you an do so using [call_command](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/#running-management-commands-from-your-code).  That will give you the generated SQL code.

However, if you're looking for a way to generate similar SQL, you'll need to consult the documentation for your DBMS, as that will differ from database to database.